# AWS S3 'RequestTimeTooSkewed' error when uploading multiple files

Tags: javascript, node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I'm uploading multiple HTML and PNG files in a particular directory structure to my AWS S3 bucket.  The code I wrote to upload these files has worked perfectly fine up until now.

Recently, I have been experiencing many "RequestTimeTooSkewed" errors as the upload process nears its completion.  The message "The difference between the request time and the current time is too large" is provided as well.

I should mention that I am daily uploading more and more PNG files with each execution.  For example, I used to upload about 500 PNG files.  The next day, I may be uploading 700 PNG files.  I am now uploading about 2,500 PNG files per execution.

I understand that this issue occurs when the AWS S3 server's time does not match the machine running the uploading script's time.  I have checked my machine's time against the server's time and found that both times are virtually identical.

I am wondering if the uploading files are getting bottlenecked and are initially given an earlier time than when the actual upload begins.

If anyone has any idea why these errors are happening, I would love to hear an explanation.  Thank you!!

Here is the code responsible for uploading to AWS S3:

```
let fs = require('fs');
let rimraf = require('rimraf');
let directory = 'reporting/reports/';
let aws = require('aws-sdk');

let date;
let screenshotFolder = [];
let OSFolder = [];
let hubFolder = [];

aws.config.update({
    accessKeyId: '***',
    secretAccessKey: '***',
    region: 'us-west-2'
});

let s3 = new aws.S3({
    apiVersion: "2006-03-01",
});

fs.readdirSync(directory).forEach(file => {
    date = file;
});

directory = directory + date + "/";

fs.readdirSync(directory).forEach(file => {
    if (file === ".DS_Store") {
        rimraf.sync(file);
    }
});

if (fs.existsSync(directory + "screenshots/")) {
    fs.readdirSync(directory + "screenshots/").forEach(file => {
        screenshotFolder.push(file);
    });

    for (let i = 0; i < screenshotFolder.length; ++i) {
        let fileStream = fs.createReadStream(directory + "screenshots/" + screenshotFolder[i]);
        fileStream.on('error', function (err) {
            console.log("ERROR: ", err);
        });
        s3.upload({
            Bucket: 'Reporting',
            Key: "Reporting/" + date + "/screenshots/" + screenshotFolder[i],
            Body: fileStream,
            ACL: 'public-read'
        }, function (err, data) {
            if (err) {
                console.log("Screenshot Error: ", err);
            }
            if (data) {
                console.log("Screenshot Success: ", data.Location);
            }
        }).on('httpUploadProgress', event => {
            console.log(`Screenshot Uploaded ${event.loaded} out of ${event.total}`);
        });
    }
}

if (fs.existsSync(directory + "hub/")) {
    fs.readdirSync(directory + "hub/").forEach(file => {
        hubFolder.push(file);
    });

    for (let i = 0; i < hubFolder.length; ++i) {
        let fileStream = fs.createReadStream(directory + "hub/" + hubFolder[i]);
        fileStream.on('error', function (err) {
            console.log("ERROR: ", err);
        });
        s3.upload({
            Bucket: 'Reporting',
            Key: "Reporting/" + date + "/hub/" + hubFolder[i],
            Body: fileStream,
            ACL: 'public-read',
            ContentType: 'text/html'
        }, function (err, data) {
            if (err) {
                console.log("Hub Error: ", err);
            }
            if (data) {
                console.log("Hub Success: ", data.Location);
            }
        }).on('httpUploadProgress', event => {
            console.log(`Hub Uploaded ${event.loaded} out of ${event.total}`);
        });
    }
}

fs.readdirSync(directory).forEach(file => {
    if (file !== "screenshots"  && file !== "hub" && file !== ".DS_Store") {
        OSFolder.push(file);
    }
});

for (let i = 0; i < OSFolder.length; ++i) {
    fs.readdirSync(directory + OSFolder[i]).forEach(file => {
        fs.readdirSync(directory + OSFolder[i] + "/" + file).forEach(html => {
            let fileStream = fs.createReadStream(directory + OSFolder[i] + "/" + file + "/" + html);
            fileStream.on('error', function (err) {
                console.log("OS ERROR: ", err);
            });
            s3.upload({
                Bucket: 'Reporting',
                Key: "Reporting/" + date + "/" + OSFolder[i] + "/" + file + "/" + html,
                Body: fileStream,
                ACL: 'public-read',
                ContentType: 'text/html'
            }, function (err, data) {
                if (err) {
                    console.log("OS Error: ", err);
                }
                if (data) {
                    console.log("OS Success: ", data.Location);
                }
            }).on('httpUploadProgress', event => {
                console.log(`OS Uploaded ${event.loaded} out of ${event.total}`);
            });
        });
    });
}
```

Comment: Is this machine actually time-synced via NTP or equivalent? How are you calculating the "AWS S3 server's time"? When you say "both times are virtually identical", any chance the local time is actually in the future, even a little?

Comment: @jarmod Thanks for the quick reply.  I've run `curl http://s3.amazonaws.com -v` and `date -u` commands to determine both the AWS server's time and my own machine's time.  They are identical.  Even if they were off, why are most files being uploaded while only a small minority are not? Shouldn't they all fail if the times were off?

Comment: The only thing I can think of here is to capture the network traffic from the client, verify the date and/or x-amz-date headers are within 15 minutes of S3/NTP time. If they are then report an issue to AWS with the network capture, S3 date/time, and request IDs.